# How do I tell Windows to use a specific monitor's driver instead of the generic PnP driver?

Tags: drivers, windows-vista, display

My BenQ screen looks unsharp and grainy. I downloaded a new driver from BenQ site, but I don't know how to install it. Windows Vista's hardware manager shows "Generic PnP monitor". How to install my downloaded driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drivers should contain an file with .INF extension. You can try to right-click it and select "Install".

If that does not help, in the Device manager, locate the "Generic PnP monitor" and right-click it. Select "Properties" and the monitor properties dialog will show.

Switch to Driver tab and select "Update Driver...", then "Browse my computer for driver software" and "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer".

On next dialog, select "Have Disk..." and locate the folder where you downloaded the driver (either type it in or use the Browse button - be warned this can take some time). Click OK.

Now the list of devices supported by the drivers should show up - select the right one and install it.